# ATI Radeon X1250 graphics driver 64 bit laptop

Tags: drivers, 64-bit

I have check that other topic before about ATI mobility in a laptop but don't see it for the x1250.

Any help would be great

Running windows 7, 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Vista x64 driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Legacy/Pages/integrated_vista64.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.3.3.1.3.1&product2=2.7.3.3.1.3.4&lang=English) should work on Windows 7, the card is integrated into the motherboard and is considered legacy already by AMD unfortunately, so I don't think an official one will pop up for Windows 7.